# How to make Bootstrap Datepicker returns number of days instead of date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, bootstrap-datepicker

After having searched all over SO to find an answer to my issue, I'm resolved to post a new question : my problem is I want that instead of having Bootstrap Datepicker returns a date, I want it to return the number of days between today and the selected date.

My piece of code is:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
            language: 'fr',
            startDate: new Date(),
            autoclose: true
        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            var start = moment(e.date);
            var end   = moment(new Date());
            var diff = start.diff(end, 'days'); // returns correct number
            $(this).val(diff); // doesn't seem to have any effect
        });
```

Even if I use `return diff`, `#datepicker` will always show selected date when I want the number of days between the two dates.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 inputs, and one icon, use the icon for the click, and set the value in the other input instead that the one used for the datepicker

```
<input id="diffInput"  />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input id="DONTUSEME" type='text' class="form-control" style="display:none"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                    language: 'fr',
                    startDate: new Date(),
                    autoclose: true
                }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
                    var start = moment(e.date);
                    var end   = moment(new Date());
                    var diff = start.diff(end, 'days'); // returns correct number
                    $('#diffInput').val(diff); // doesn't seem to have any effect
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

you will have to work a little bit with the css to make them keep together.